# Why does Error() have priority over String()

Tags: string, go

I've been looking through the tour for go, and I can't figure out why this happens.

When you have a `Stringer` (`String() string`), `fmt` will use that method for printing to console. Like suggested in https://tour.golang.org/methods/6

However if you add `Error() string`, this method gets called instead of `String() string`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (p *Person) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v (%v years)", p.Name, p.Age)
}

func (p *Person) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Failed")
}

func main() {
    a := &Person{"Arthur Dent", 42}
    z := &Person{"Zaphod Beeblebrox", 9001}
    fmt.Println(a, z)
}
```

Results:

> Failed Failed

I don't understand why `fmt.Println` uses `Error` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply because this is how it is implemented. An `error` is more important in practice, so if the `error` interface is implemented, that will be printed.

This is documented, read the package doc of [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> Except when printed using the verbs %T and %p, special formatting considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces. In order of application:
>
> 1. If an operand implements the Formatter interface, it will be invoked. Formatter provides fine control of formatting.
> 2. If the %v verb is used with the # flag (%#v) and the operand implements the GoStringer interface, that will be invoked.
>
> If the format (which is implicitly %v for Println etc.) is valid for a string (%s %q %v %x %X), the following two rules apply:
>
> 3. If an operand implements the **error** interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
> 4. If an operand implements method **String() string**, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

So `error` is 3<sup>rd</sup> on the list while `String()` is only 4<sup>th</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple: when *fmt* uses any of it's print functions, it does a type switch for each argument to determine how it should be printed, and in that type switch `case error` appears just before `case Stringer`.