# Struct embedding and ambiguity resolution

Tags: go

In Golang structure embedding I have created an ambiguity. Embedded struct have and field num, and container struct too have a field num.

```
type base struct {
    num int
}


type container struct {
    base
    str string
    num int
}
```

While referencing, it resolved as follows, and is it legal and correct use?

`container.num - resolved to outer`
&
`container.base.num - resolved to inner`

Answer (score 2):

Embedding is never a problem. Fields and methods of the embedded type get promoted, and if the [selector](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Selectors) expression is not ambiguous, you may use it.

If the embedder type also has a field name the same as a field that could get promoted, that's also not a problem, but obviously `container.num` can't designate 2 different fields, only one. The language spec properly defines what that will be. [Spec: Selectors:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Selectors)

> The following rules apply to selectors:
>
> 1. For a value `x` of type `T` or `*T` where `T` is not a pointer or interface type, `x.f` denotes **the field or method at the shallowest depth in `T` where there is such an `f`. If there is not exactly one `f` with shallowest depth, the selector expression is illegal.**
>
> [...]

So the "shallowest" in your case is `container.num`, not `container.base.num`. No ambiguity here.

Let's see another example;

```
type base struct {
    num int
}

type base2 struct {
    num int
}

type container struct {
    base
    base2
    str string
}
```

`container` embeds `base` and `base2`, and both have a field named `num`. Again, this embedding itself is not a problem. You can also refer to those fields using `container.base.num` and `container.base2.num`. But if you'd write `container.num`, since there are not one (but 2) fields denoted by `container.num` at the shallowest depth (depth = 1), the selector expression is invalid and would result in a compile-time error.

See related: [Weird Behavior of String() Method on Embedded Types in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67519749/weird-behavior-of-string-method-on-embedded-types-in-go/67520517#67520517)